# Calculating values in rows one by one using sum() over(partition by)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, partition-by

I have the following table (TableX):

[image]

The goal is to calculate the changes per account_id and display the ending value:

[image]

Thus, when account_id=1, the value is 500-100=400 and when account_id=2, the value is 300+100-300=100.

I tried the following query but it doesn't give the result that I wish:

```
SELECT SUM(change) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id) FROM TableX GROUP BY Account_id
```

Comment: Is this MySQL ?!

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use `SUM` as an aggregate function here:

```sql
SELECT Account_id, SUM(change)
FROM TableX
GROUP BY Account_id;
```

Here is how you could use `SUM()` as an analytic function *without* `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT Account_id, Change, SUM(change) OVER (PARTITION BY Account_id) total
FROM TableX
ORDER BY Account_id;
```

This would generate the following output:

```
Account_id | Change | total
1          | 500    | 400
1          | -100   | 400
2          | 300    | 100
2          | 100    | 100
2          | -300   | 100
```

As you can see, the analytic function version of your query returns all original records in the table.

Comment: Thanks! How would you go about calculating the max account balance for each account_id? (Account_id 1 would be 500 and Account_id 2 would be 400)

Comment: You would need to also let us know which column provides the _ordering_ for the transactions.  By the way, your original question has already been answered.

Comment: The column "id" in TableX provides the ordering. Id 1 = first transaction, id5=last transaction